# code shows type error must be str, not int

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Account:
  def __init__(self,balance):
    self._balance = balance
  def getBalance(self):
    return self._balance

class CheckingAccount(Account):
  numberOfAccount = 0
  
  def __init__(self,balance=0):
    self.balance = balance 
    super().__init__(balance)
    CheckingAccount.numberOfAccount =+ 1
  
  def __str__(self):
    return 'Account Balance: '+str(self.balance) 

print('Number of Checking Accounts: '+CheckingAccount.numberOfAccount)
print(CheckingAccount())
print(CheckingAccount(100.00))
print(CheckingAccount(200.00))
print('Number of Checking Accounts: '+CheckingAccount.numberOfAccount)
```

the code shows an error because int doesn't concatenate with str. the object part of the code can't be changed. so how can i fix the code so it shows the following output:

```
Number of Checking
Accounts: 0
Account Balance: 0.0
Account Balance: 100.0
Account Balance: 200.0
Number of Checking
Accounts: 3
```

Comment: You should probably use the `str` method https://www.journaldev.com/23642/python-concatenate-string-and-int

Comment: Or use a formatting operator.

Comment: Don't concatenate str to int.  In the `print` functions, use a comma instead of a plus.  Print knows how to print integers.

Comment: i'm not allowed to change the codes in the print function. i can only change the codes in CheckingAccount class.

Comment: Then your teacher forced you to use incorrect code.  You have to make `numberOfAcccount` a `str` then, in the class, which makes incrementing it a pain.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace some "+" with ","
then it should work fine.

Comment: Read the comments.  OP says can't change that part of this homework.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the first and last print statements you have. You are trying to concatenate a string with an int. To fix this you can quite a few things. I will show you two ways.

1.

```
# Use format
print("Number of Checking Accounts: {}".format(CheckingAccount.numberOfAccount))
```

2. 

```
# Use str
print("Number of Checking Accounts: " + str(CheckingAccount.numberOfAccount))
```

There are many other ways to do it these are just two ways that it can be done.

Comment: Read the comments.  OP says can't change that part of this homework.

Comment: You can change how you increment the number. Try doing CheckingAccount.numberOfAccount = str(int(CheckingAccount.numberOfAccount) + 1)  and replace numberOfAccount = 0 with numberOfAccount = "0". This is an odd ball way to do this but it is the simplest way I can think of doing this. Hope this helps.

Comment: Python "teachers" often don't know the language well themselves.

Answer (score 0):

there should be "," not "+"

```
  def __init__(self,balance):
    self._balance = balance
  def getBalance(self):
    return self._balance

class CheckingAccount(Account):
  numberOfAccount = 0
  
  def __init__(self,balance=0):
    self.balance = balance 
    super().__init__(balance)
    CheckingAccount.numberOfAccount+= 1
  
  def __str__(self):
    return 'Account Balance: '+str(self.balance) 

print('Number of Checking Accounts: ',CheckingAccount.numberOfAccount)
print(CheckingAccount())
print(CheckingAccount(100.00))
print(CheckingAccount(200.00))
print('Number of Checking Accounts: ',CheckingAccount.numberOfAccount)
```